# Missing `secret_token` and `secret_key_base` for 'development' environment, set these values in `config/secrets.yml`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

When I try to run `rails server` command I get the error

[image]

How to solve it?

My **config/environments/development.rb**

```
Rails.application.configure do

  config.secret_key_base = ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"]

  #Some stuff 

end
```

And I don't have the **secret.yml** file in my folder.

[image]

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Then create one:

#### config/secrets.yml

```
# be sure to restart your server when you modify this file...
# Make sure the secret is at least 30 characters and all random,
# no regular words or you'll be exposed to dictionary attacks.
development:
  secret_key_base:  asdflkjasdlfkjasldfkj

test:
  secret_key_base:  asdflkhasldfhlhaskdlflakhsdf

production:
  secret_key_base: 523lk5h2lkjlj6nlk4n6lk4
```

obviously don't use those keys above ^ just mash on your keyboard, or use `rake secret` to generate one `:)`

Comment: Don't explicitly set production env's `secret_key_base`, use `secret_key_base: <%= ENV['MY_ENV_VAR'] %>` instead. Of course you have to set the environment variable `MY_ENV_VAR`.

Answer (score 2):

You skipped one installation step.

For Redmine 2 and 3 versions, type:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake generate_secret_token
```

Answer (score 1):

The following solution helped me:

Create a secrets.yml file in your config directory.

In your terminal, type the following command: rake secret. This will generate a secret for you to include in your secrets.yml file.

Add the following snippet of code to your config/secrets.yml file:

development:
  secret_key_base: PASTE_YOUR_GENERATED_SECRET_HERE

Answer (score 1):

My solution to the problem is creating a new project then copy the 'secrets.yml` from the newly generated app into the old project.

```
rails new TmpApp

cd TmpApp/config

cp secrets.yml /Path/to/old/project/config/
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this same issue with Redmine. There is a Rake task to generate it. It does not need to go into a Yaml file. It goes into a secret_tocken.rb file in the initializers folder.