# Ruby on Rails wrong path to logs (on Windows)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railsinstaller

I have a problem with Ruby on Rails setup after re-installing Windows 10. I used RailsInstaller (v. 3.2.0 - with Ruby 2.2.0 and Rails 4.2.6).

After installation I fixed path error in *.bat files (as usual, u know), create new project and run bundle. Everything going fine.

Then I ran my project and had seen this errors in output:

1.

```
config.eager_load is set to nil. Please update your config/environments/*.rb files accordingly:

  * development - set it to false
  * test - set it to false (unless you use a tool that preloads your test environment)
  * production - set it to true
```

(Actually all of this is set up correctly)

2. Rails Error: Unable to access log file. Please ensure that C:/Users/home/Dropbox/test_app/log/C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/bin/.log exists and is writable (ie, make it writable for user and group: chmod 0664 C:/Users/home/Dropbox/test_app/log/C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/bin/.log). The log level has been raised to WARN and the output directed to STDERR until the problem is fixed.

As you can see - the logs path are completly wrong and logs directory is empty.

Then server runs, but in browser I've also got an error:

```
Internal Server Error

    Missing `secret_token` and `secret_key_base` for 'C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.2.0\bin\' environment, set these values in `config/secrets.yml`
```

Again - that's not a path to my project. 
Any ideas?

Comment: you see this post more details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32397607/missing-secret-token-and-secret-key-base-for-development-environment-set

Comment: @Jack I already tried it.  All keys are configured.